# SoftwareSerial communication to RS232 device with Arduino HEX

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno, serial-communication

Hi everyone hope you are fine,

my problem is
when i send a frame ( FE FE FE FE 68 99 99 99 99 99 99 68 23 0A 60 00 34 12 78 56 BC 9A F0 DE 2B 16) via an rs232 cable with my laptop i can get the response with docklight like (FE FE FE FE 68 99 99 99 99 99 99 68 23 02 60 80 6B 16) but now i want to get the response via arduino so i did this connection   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K68zU.jpg)

with the following code but i did not get any response (just 0000000000...)

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
#define pinTX 2

#define pinRX 4

byte data[47];

SoftwareSerial RS232(pinRX, pinTX);
static byte trame1[]     = {0xFE,0xFE,0xFE,0xFE,0x68,0x99,0x99,0x99,0x99,0x99,0x99,0x68,0x23,0x0A,0x60,0x00,0x34,0x12,0x78,0x56,0xBC,0x9A,0xF0,0xDE,0x2B,0x16}; 

void setup() {


 RS232.begin(9600);
Serial.begin(9600);

Serial.println("Starting");

}

void loop() {

for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
RS232.write(trame1[i]);

  }

while (RS232.available()){

RS232.readBytes(data, 18);
 }
 delay(1000);
for (int i=0;i<47;i++){
Serial.print(data[i]) ;
  }
Serial.print("\n") ;
delay(5000);  
}
```

Comment: use `Serial.write(data[i])`

Comment: @Juraj It s already used in the code: (RS232.write(trame1[i]))

Comment: @Juraj thank you for your help, but it just gives me the same input frame in ASCII 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfr2X.jpg

Comment: For the code it same that is mentionned i did not change anything just the line: RS232.write(trame1[i]);
i change it as you said with : Serial.write(trame1[i]);

Comment: I meant `Serial.print(data[i])` to `Serial.write(data[i])`, but maybe `Serial.print(data[i], HEX)` would be better

Comment: @Juraj it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going from the SoftwareSerial TX and RX pins on the Arduino to the RS-232 cable and checking the data gets transferred that way?  It could be an issue with the voltage levels.  If you set up the Arduino to spam out a string and you can see that when you patch it into the RS-232 cable then you know you voltage and connections are correct.  If it doesn't, check the voltage levels because the Arduino is only 5V.  You should also check that TX and RX didn't get swapped.